# Problems on call retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I newbie on kotlin, its my firts app test. I trying to do a retrofit call (POST) but i get sintax error on create code.

My syntax error: no type arguments expected for CallBack

this is my doLogin function on presenter layer (i got error here):

```
override fun doLogin() {
    val call = RetrofitInitializer().loginApiContract().login()

    call.enqueue(object: Callback<UserAccount> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserAccount>?,
                                response: Response<UserAccount) {
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserAccount>?,
                               t: Throwable?) {
        }
    })
}
```

and that is my retrofit initializer:

```
class RetrofitInitializer {

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.23:8080/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    fun loginApiContract() : LoginApiContract{
        return retrofit.create(LoginApiContract::class.java)
    }

}
```

that is my interface of call:

```
interface LoginApiContract {

    @POST("login")
    fun login() : Call<UserAccount>

    @GET("statements")
    fun getStatements()
}
```

Comment: I think you should also attach LoginApiContract sources.

Comment: now you can see (:

Comment: Please make sure that the import statement for Callback references the correct Callback class. Looks like you've accidentally imported a class with the same name from a different package.

Comment: you are right!! sorry for the newbie question hehe and thx for the help.

Comment: I thought you might have taken care of import statements, so didn't bother mentioning it. Lol

Answer (score 1):

Best practice with kotlin - use rxjava calladapter factory.

Try to add dependency

compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:"

and add call adapter factory

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.23:8080/")
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

Comment: Hi, he fixed it. It was some problem with imports